# Best way to distribute an R/Shiny app to be run by a user on local computer?

Tags: r, github, shiny, software-distribution

I have developed a Shiny app for a user at a different location. This app may eventually be hosted in the cloud but for now a single user will run the application locally on their computer. What is the preferred way to share the application and also make it easy to maintain/update the scripts?

Do I need to instruct the user to install R, RStudio, all of the packages used by the application, and copy the R scripts, etc, to a local directory, and then include directions about how to run from the RStudio interface?

I'm intrigued by the runGitHub option, which seems very appealing, with one problem: It wouldn't be wise to add the file containing API tokens in the GitHub repository. Is there a way for the code to look for that specific file locally instead of in the repository?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [{dotenv}](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/dotenv)  to store the secrets. For example,

1. create a `.env` in your app root folder.

In the file

```bash
username=xxxxxx
token="xxxxxx"
```

2. Make a copy of this file called `.env-template`.
3. Add `.env` but not `.env-template` to `.gitignore`.
4. Fill your real tokens in `.env` since this file will not be uploaded to github.
5. In R, use

```r
# load secrets
library(dotenv)
load_dot_env('.env')
# to get values 
Sys.getenv("username")
Sys.getenv("token")
```

6. Tell users to fill their real tokens in `.env-template` and rename it to `.env`

#### to use `runGithub` or `runGist`

The demo is very simple, just to get the secret token locally while running app from a remote address.

Your app code

```r
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  print(Sys.getenv("token")) # just print out the token on console 
}
shinyApp(div(), server)
```

User code will be like

```r
library(shiny)
### first run without following 4 lines and then uncomment following and run again
### watch the difference on console 
# library(dotenv)
# dotenv_file <- tempfile()
# cat('token=12345', file = dotenv_file)
# load_dot_env(dotenv_file)
###
runGist('https://gist.github.com/lz100/f54d59901a56a051770edd77e1324f21')
```

Comment: This is so helpful. One question: is there a way to load all values in the .env file into the workspace without having to specify each variable one at a time with Sys.getenv("variablename")? From the documentation for dotenv it appears that the library(dotenv) call should load everything in the root .env file into memory but when I execute llibrary(dotenv), only the first line (the first variable and value) are loaded in the workspace

Comment: You can call `envs<-Sys.getenv()` to load all variables into an object and call `envs['variablename']` to get the value you want. I just tested with multiple lines of variables, everything worked fine, can't reproduce the situation you talked about.

Comment: In my test, this does not work with runGitHub... I am looking for a way to distribute a Shiny application to a user to run locally, but I would like to be able to maintain the software and make it easy for them to install and run. In my test, having a local .env file does not work when running the application from runGitHub. I'm still looking for advice about the easiest way to distribute and maintain a Shiny application (while keeping secret keys out of GitHub). Thank you

Comment: @Judy See updates.